# Running jenkins on ubuntu subsystem of Windows

Tags: jenkins, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I was able to install and run jenkins on my linux subsystem in Windows 10.
It listens on 8082.
But unfortunately, for an unknown reason, it hangs up infinitely after a few minutes (or to be precise after a I've made a change in a job config and execute a build).
Then, I checked in the terminal:

```
root@jup1t3r /h/navds# service jenkins status
Correct java version found
2 instances of jenkins are running at the moment
but the pidfile /var/run/jenkins/jenkins.pid is missing
root@jup1t3r /h/navds# service jenkins stop
Correct java version found
* Stopping Jenkins Automation Server jenkins
...done.
root@jup1t3r /h/navds# service jenkins status
Correct java version found
2 instances of jenkins are running at the moment
but the pidfile /var/run/jenkins/jenkins.pid is missing
```

So there is no way to stop Jenkins. How can I restart it ?